# How to display only the appointment handled by the staff?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a procedure that display the appointment record that are only handled by specific staff. However, it is still displaying all of the appointments for this specific staff. May I know where are my mistake?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_gen_staff_detail_report(staffID IN NUMBER) IS

CURSOR appointmentDetail IS
    SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE Appointments.staffId = staffID;

v_appointmentID Appointments.id%TYPE;
v_createdAt Appointments.createdAt%TYPE;
v_bookingDateTime Appointments.bookingDateTime%TYPE;
v_petID Appointments.petId%TYPE;
v_roomID Appointments.roomId%TYPE;
    BEGIN
    OPEN appointmentDetail;
    LOOP
        FETCH appointmentDetail INTO v_appointmentID, v_createdAt, v_bookingDateTime, v_petID, v_roomID, v_staffID;
        EXIT WHEN appointmentDetail%NOTFOUND;
        appointmentCount := appointmentCount + 1;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD(v_appointmentID, 6, ' ') || ' ' || RPAD(v_createdAt, 30, ' ') || ' ' || RPAD(v_bookingDateTime, 30, ' ')
        || ' ' || RPAD(v_petID, 10, ' ') || ' ' || RPAD(v_roomID, 10, ' '));
        
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE appointmentDetail;
    END;
    /
```

[image]

Comment: Can you change input parameter name to anything other than column name of the table.

Comment: Yes, it finally work ! Didn't realize the oracle sql is not sensitive at all..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_gen_staff_detail_report(staffID IN NUMBER) IS

CURSOR appointmentDetail IS
    SELECT * FROM Appointments WHERE Appointments.staffId = staffID;
```

Your parameter name is the same as the name of column in the WHERE clause change it to something like

```sql
PROCEDURE proc_gen_staff_detail_report(p_staffID IN NUMBER)
...
  WHERE Appointments.staffId = p_staffID;
```

Comment: It has solved my issues, thank you very much !! I have searching solution around 1 hours for this thing ._.

Comment: You are wellcome. Regards...